# ScrollView offsets when superview is setframe?! (iphone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

So i have a View and a scroll view inside that view.  I call a

```
[View setFrame:CGRectMake(55,70,260,420)];
```

i put a

```
NSLog(@"%f %f",scrollview.frame.origin.x, scrollview.frame.origin.y);
```

before and after the setFrame and it reads 6,112 and then 6,172.  112 is correct, i have no idea where the 60 comes from.  i searched 60 in my implementation file, and there is nothing that could affect the y at all.  is there some rule with doing a setframe when there is a view inside that view?

Thanks

Comment: you have'nt show 60 in ouput in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making the scrollview in my code instead of doing it through the XIB.  the scrollview is created after the setFrame and addSubView of the parent View

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the `UIView` reference, the `frame` property states

> `frame`
>
> The frame rectangle, which describes the view’s location and size in
>   its superview’s coordinate system. 
>    `@property(nonatomic) CGRect frame`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This rectangle defines the size and position of the view in its
>   superview’s coordinate system. You use this rectangle during layout
>   operations to size and position the view. Setting this property
>   changes the point specified by the center property and the size in the
>   bounds rectangle accordingly. The coordinates of the frame rectangle
>   are always specified in points.

So i guess when you `NSLog` the frame for scrollview it is displayed based on the coordinates of the superview. The second `NSLog` shows different because the superview's coordinate system has changed.

Comment: yeah that would make sense if the 55 was added to the x, and 70 was added to the y, but only 60 is added to the y.  Also, looking at the subview, everything else (buttons, labels, imageviews) is positioned properly, only the scrollview is visibly off